# Does there exist a physical device which can batch scan playing-card sized media?

Tags: scanner, scanning

I have a Xerox WorkCentre at home, but the document feeder does not seem to work on poker cards. I have also seen various business card scanning devices, such as [this one](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000H1F9IA), but I am not sure if they can handle cards as large as poker cards.

Does anyone know of a device that can batch scan (with an automatic feeder) poker-sized cards?

Answer (score 0):

Some MFPs (and perhaps your Xerox WorkCentre) accept card sized paper only when you insert it the right way. If it does not pull in the cards in vertical orientation, try it in horizontal. Often it is also necessary to adjust the document guides to match the width of the cards so that they are properly fed in.

Regarding a business card scanner: Check the technical specs at the manufacturer's website. They should mention the maximum dimensions possible.

Alternative: Search for "portable document scanner" and you will find scanners in a similar price range as business card scanners that should be able to handle your poker cards.